# Why does this statue have five legs?

Tags: classical-antiquity, sculpture

Bulls have 4 legs. These statues have 5 legs. Why?

[image: Photo of a lamassu]

[image: Museum sign, transcribed below]

> ## Khorsabad
>
> ## The Palace of Sargon
>
> This area mainly contains sculptures from the city and palace of Khorsabad, built for the Assyrian king Sargon II (721-705 BC). The pair of human-headed winged bulls stood originally at one of the gates of the citadel, as magic guardians against misfortune.

Comment: This is not a horse.

Comment: I know but it's horse based

Comment: `Bulls have 4 legs. These statues have 5 legs. Why?` Bulls also do not have human heads

Comment: They have five legs when they're happy

Comment: Lol.I see what you did there

Answer (score 53):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamassu),

> The Assyrians typically prominently placed lamassu at the entrances of
>   cities and palaces. From the front they appear to stand, and from the
>   side, walk.

Something confirmed by the [New York Metropolitan Museum of Art](http://www.metmuseum.org/toah/works-of-art/32.143.2):

> The sculptor gave these guardian figures five legs so that they appear
>   to be standing firmly when viewed from the front but striding forward
>   when seen from the side.

The statue is called a *lamassu*, and it's Assyrian, not Egyptian.

Comment: See also: [Assyrian sculpture (Lamassu) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assyrian_sculpture#Lamassu)

Answer (score 11):

I think that if you view the statue from head-on, you only see the front two legs.  If you view the statue from the side, you see four.  At that time, they probably couldn't just clear away all the rest of the rock so that you could see four legs from any direction.

Answer (score -5):

The 5 legs represent the five pillars of the Assyrian empire.

1. mental health
2. emotional health
3. spiritual health
4. physical health
5. culture health.

These were basic requirements of every man and woman that was to protect and defend the Assyrian Assyria. As a protector of the sacred places the Lamassu also named nathoora which means protector.

Comment: Can you provide some sources to back that up. That is interesting. Not sure why someone would downvote this without more info, though.